# Django ORM query, manytomany self referenced with left join and where

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I need to translate one query.

Models

```
class Publication_dependecy(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.id))

class Publication(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)

    name = models.TextField()


class Publication_relationship(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.publication_from + '#' + self,publication + '#' + self.publication_dependecy_id)

    from_publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, related_name='from_publication', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, related_name='to_publication', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publication_dependecy = models.ForeignKey(Publication_dependecy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

SQL query:

```
select Publication.id
from Publication
left join Publication_relationship on
    Publication.id = Publication_relationship.from_publication
where
    publication_dependecy.id is NULL or Publication_dependecy.id = 1
```

I need to retrive all publications that are not in Publication_relationship or  his publication_dependecy is 1. In other words publication_dependency is 1 or NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Publication.objects.filter(to_publication__publication_dependecy__isnull=True).filter(to_publication__publication_dependecy__id=1).values_list('id', Flat=True)
```

That would be your query. What do you mean with  *publication_dependency is 1* because publication_dependency is an object not an integer or a charField type value, for that reason I suppose you refer to the id. Tell me if that works

Comment: Sorry I don't understant how it works this ORM:
"Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'publication_relationship' into field. Choices are: from_publication, id, name, related_to, relationship, to_publication

Comment: @guibos I edit, tell me. But should work like a I put before

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = (Publication.objects
      .filter(Q(to_publication__publication_dependecy__isnull=True) | 
              Q(to_publication__publication_dependecy__id=1))
      .values_list('id', Flat=True)
)
```